# Cache that always returns immediate response?

Tags: cache

I have a web service that takes a while to build a response despite being tuned as best I can.

What I'd like is some sort of cache sitting in front of the service which would always return the last known value from the service, but at the same time pass the request back to the service to build an up to date response for the next request.

I'm aware of the limitations that this puts on the freshness of the data, but you can assume that I'm happy to live with that.

The technologies I'm using at present are python uwsgi via nginx, but that need not be a limit to any solution you might suggest.

Col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a reverse proxy you can use Varnish in saint mode or squid with stale-if-error directive.

If you want in-app cache, using memcached for example, just don't rely on storage expiry mechanism - store expiry with cached object `array(cached_object=>object, expiry=>timestamp)` and react if you encounter stale cache: increase expiry to now + a bit of time (to prevent dogpiling - multiple processes regenerating cache in parallel), use stale cache, initialize update.

Comment: That Memcache solution looks like I can make it work. Thanks, FYI NGinX has proxy_cache_use_stale which I get the impression might also have been usable, but couldn't quite figure out how. Cheers.

Comment: AFAIK all you need is `proxy_cache_use_stale updating;` and is should just work.